# Enable/disable key listener when a component is focused/defocused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events

I have an app (react/redux) which is split in to two parts:

- a Grid (wysiwyg), consisting of GridAreas and GridAreaElements
- a GridEditor

I'd like to have a *key listener* for the Grid that listens to key presses.
E.g. pressing *down* should select the next GridArea(Element), and pressing *Escape* should select the "parent", if applicable.

In the GridEditor, you can edit properties on the various GridAreaElements etc. via e.g. input fields. When interacting with the GridEditor, and especially these input fields, I **don't** want the key press listener to be enabled, as it can e.g. deselect the element that is being edited.

So what I'd like is to enable the key listener when the Grid component (and its children) is focused/active, but **disable** it when the Grid is blurred/inactive, i.e. the GridEditor is focused/active.

Are there any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Not sure if it's the best solution though.

First of all, to make an event listener fire on events on a DOM element, e.g. a `div`, the element it is attached to must have focus. We can make sure an element is focusable by giving it a `tabIndex`:

```
<div className="myDiv" tabIndex="0" ref="myDiv" >
```

By also adding a `ref` to the div, we can access the DOM element and attach a keydown event listener to it in `componentDidMount`:

```
this.refs.myDiv.addEventListener('keydown', this.props.handleKeyPress, false)
```

This keydown listener will only be triggered when the DOM element it is attached to is focused :)